# How can I append switches to the existing value of the TikZ font key?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

Is it possible to append switches to the existing settings for the TikZ `font` key?

For example, suppose that I want all nodes to be in the `\sffamily` typeface.  This can be done by setting `every node/.append style={font=\sffamily}`.  I might later wish to have a node that inherits the `every node` `font` settings and, additionally, uses the italic shape `\itshape`.  Unfortunately, as the following shows, it does not work to simply add `font=\itshape`; doing so overrides the previous `font` setting, and the default type family (in italic) is used.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={font=\sffamily}]
    \node {Sans serif};
    \node [font=\itshape] at (3,0) {Sans serif, italic};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Digging through the manual, I found the `<key>/.append` handler, which looked promising.

> Key handler `<key>/.append={<append value>}`
>   Adds the `<append value>` at the end of the value stored in `<key>`.

What if I used `font/.append=\itshape`?  Well, this does not work either:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={font=\sffamily}]
    \node {Sans serif};
    \node [font/.append=\itshape] at (3,0) {Sans serif, italic};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thus, I have two questions:

- Why does `font/.append=\itshape` not work here?
- How can I append switches to the existing settings for `font`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an answer to the second question; I do not know why `font/.append=\itshape` does not work.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{font append/.style={font/.expand once=\tikz@textfont #1},
         font append/.value required}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={font=\sffamily}]
    \node {Sans serif};
    \node [font append=\itshape] at (3,0) {Sans serif, italic};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's why this works:  The `font` key is (roughly) defined with

```
\tikzset{font/.code=\def\tikz@textfont{#1}}
```

When needed, the value for `font` is then accessed through
`\tikz@textfont`.  So, the solution is to expand `\tikz@textfont` to
get the current value of `font`, and then manually append whatever
font switches we want.

However, I do not know why `font` stores its value in `\tikz@textfont`
rather than being a value-key directly.

Comment: You have to append `font={\sffamily\itshape}`. Actually you have to overwrite as they are not cumulative properties.

Comment: @percusse Yes, I could just write `font={\sffamily\itshape}`, but what if I change the `every node` style to have, say, `font=\ttfamily` (or even some other typeface included via the `fontspec` package in XeLaTeX)?  This way, I don't have to remember to also update the `font` value for the second node.  (I know, I know, I shouldn't be so greedy... `:)`)  What I don't understand is why the value is stored in `\tikz@textfont` rather than directly in the key itself (i.e., use `\pgfkeysvalueof` to get the value).

Comment: Because the mechanism is different. As I said the keys are not commutative. so they cannot be accumulated. Also the mechanism is a code not a style so if you want to pull the current value you have to pull back a macro not a value. Supoose you have keys `[bold,italic]` the result won't be bold and italic but just italic. Since each will call a different macro. Also the code goes into a box and immediately forgotten once the `\nodeparttextbox` is established. So pulling back the value is double difficult.

Comment: @percusse Oh, that explanation for why `\pgfkeysvalueof` doesn't work (i.e., that it's a `/.code` not a `/.style`) makes sense.  But isn't this a design decision in TikZ?  Couldn't one imagine an alternate implementation of the `font` key that stores the value directly in the key rather than in a macro via the `/.code` handler?  Then, the imaginary implementation of `\nodeparttextbox` would use `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/font}` in place of `\tikz@textfont`.  Would that implementation fail because some code goes into a box, as you point out?

Comment: That's seemingly possible but note that tikz inherits the text properties from its environment and the text typesetting is done out of TikZ. That's why you get a nice blend when you place a TikZ picture inside a document which uses a different font. Therefore, TikZ doesn't actually draw the text which would be great if it did so but that's an incredible task hence only strong externals such as PS can handle such complications. So any key would be pointless unless TeX understands what to do. Right now, by design, TikZ just leaves the box handling to TeX but draws anything else by itself.

Comment: You can still place the additional code via `/.prefix code` or `/.append code` or more generally `/.add code` as you did. But you have to keep in mind that anything complicated for pdflatex is also complicated for TikZ. I've asked a question about it : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60778/fundamental-differences-pstricks-tikz-pgf-and-others

Comment: @percusse Now I'm thoroughly confused: I didn't use `/.add code` (or `/.prefix code` or `/.append code`) above, or did I?  Sorry I'm being dense...

Comment: Never mind what I said :) It's more confusing to go in there since I'm not a TeXpert but there is a little more going on under the hood. So code additions are what this stuff boils down to. When the time comes, `\itshape` etc. is added before the box content inside the box. That's what I meant. In short, which code should be put, is saved in these `@` populated macros.