# Vector graphics using arbitrary functions (other than bezier, arcs etc) to create shapes

Tags: diagrams

Is it possible to create vector graphics with latex or an external program that allows the usage of more or less arbitrary functions (other than beziers and standard shapes like circles etc) to define shapes?

It would, for example, to actually use the function Y=sin(1/x) instead of having to use piecewise linear functions with finite steps. Of course the functions has to be evaluated for presentation on screen/printer, but then the steps could be adjusted to the given resolution.

If its impossible, is there a limitation in the PDF/PostScript specification that prevents it or why isn't it possible?

Comment: For arbitrary functions, I am unaware of such a feature in pdf. Perhaps in postscript? Why is it insufficient to interpolate your shape using (lots of!) cubic polynomials (the highest degree of smoothness which is supported by pdf)? Note that `x^2` *can* be represented exactly by a cubic polynomial without interpolation errors.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Perhaps x^2 was a poorly chosen example. I'll edit it to sin(1/x). That function will always be represented poorly if one uses piecewise linear functions of you look close enough.

Comment: Either you use Bézier curves or plot points; I don't think that *any* software that represents curves uses linear functions, but rather approximates them with Bézier curves. As far as the function sin(1/x) is concerned, it's *impossible* to represent it in the vicinity of 0, for *any* software in whatsoever fashion.

Comment: With the current PDF specifications you don't need a holistic representation. Vector graphics inherently assumes a certain detail negligence down to pixel size. For general purposes, `sin(1/x)` is certainly possible to draw sufficiently realistic. Otherwise you need to use a CAS which TeX is certainly not. Try this `\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}\addplot[domain=-0.01:0.01,samples=6000] {sin(1/x)};\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}`. The sensitivity can be increased if you use gnuplot as the backend.

Comment: Alternatively, read Herbert's answer here : [fundamental differences: pstricks tikz pgf and others](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60778/fundamental-differences-pstricks-tikz-pgf-and-others) and then but only then the second part of David's answer.

Comment: @percusse Thank you. I get your point of course. My example and question was purely hypothetical and of course the application of it is very limited indeed and I was pursuing the limitations of LaTeX/PDF/TikZ. The answer that tex can't be used as a CAS is enlightening.

Comment: hre is an example for sin(1/x) http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-plot/FunctionExamples#sin

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can transform *many* functions into piecewise Bezier approximations by using the derivative to calculate the inner control points (which represent tangent vectors for the curve at the end-points).

A very good write-up is Bill Casselmann's [Mathematical Illustrations](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/graphics/manual/), ch. 6 Curves and ch. 7 Drawing Curves Automatically, which I will be re-reading before saying more. But, effectively, any system which implements Bezier curves can be used to approximate other functions by sampling and interpolation.

Here's a postscript illustration. It's sometimes necessary to invent an interpretation of x/0 to allow the calculation to procede using `/div{dup 0 eq{pop pop 100000}{div}ifelse}bind def`. *Edit: modified to show endpoints of each curve.*

N=10:
[image: sin(1/x),n=10,with points]

N=100:
[image: sin(1/x),n=100,with points]

```
%!

/circ { % draw a circle at current point, radius: 3*linewidth
    gsave
        currentpoint newpath % cx cy
        currentlinewidth 3 mul % cx cy r
        0 360 % cx cy r ang^ ang$
        arc fill %draw and fill the circle
    grestore
} def

% x0 x1 N  sin1x  -
% approximate sin(1/x) in N segments with piecewise Bezier curves
% N: number of segments,
% x0,x1: endpoints (x- ordinates)
%
/sin1x { 16 dict begin
    {N x1 x0}{exch def}forall   %give names to the arguments
    /f { 1 exch div sin } def   %f(x) = sin(1/x)
    /f' { 1 exch div cos } def  %f'(x) = cos(1/x)
    /h x1 x0 sub N div def      %dx 
    /x x0 def                   %x = x0
    /y x f def                  %y = f(x)
    /s x f' def                 %s = f'(x)
    x y moveto               %place initial point at x0,f(x0)
    N {                         %repeat N times ...
        circ                    %draw circle to show endpoint
        x h 3 div add
        y h 3 div s mul add  % x+(dx/3) y+(dx/3)*s           ctrl pt 1
        /x x h add def          %x = x + dx
        /y x f def              %y = f(x)
        /s x f' def             %s = f'(x)
        x h 3 div sub
        y h 3 div s mul sub  % x+dx-(dx/3) f(x+dx)-(dx/3)*s  ctrl pt 2
        x y                  % x+dx f(x+dx)                  end pt
        curveto                 %draw curve segment, end pt becomes start of next seg
    } repeat
} def

% translate origin to roughly the center of US letter paper
300 400 translate

% scale by 200, but reduce linewidth by same proportion
% ie. scale the *drawing*, not the *image*
1 200 dup dup scale 
div currentlinewidth mul setlinewidth

%x0 x1 N 
-1 1 100 sin1x stroke
showpage
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Thanks. Stumbled on this while searching SE for anything Bezier-related. I'm a big fan of TeX and have read many things by Knuth, but I'm a little intimidated by TeX itself. As a postscript-hacker, I do greatly envy its text- and type- facilities.

Comment: My own postscript interpreter can execute the above program as of [this revision](http://code.google.com/p/xpost/source/detail?r=4642bbdded821fb2ab8104a7e186f47c85134399).

Comment: You are a PostScript master.