# How to bold figures in Latex?

Tags: floats

After sending my file to printer, I notice that some figures are very weak in print.
Is there any way to make them bold ?
I see that `\boldmath` do work on equations.

Is there any othere way to change figures to bold one as equations ?

Thanks,
Tommy

Comment: You mean `figure` the `figure` or `figure` the number? If your figure is generated by LaTeX (e.g. pstricks or pgfplots etc., there are some means) and for other occasions, just included from other figure generators those are reponsible, but if you include some `.png` or `.jpg` file you have to manipulate the image itself with `gimp` etc.

Comment: Increasing the size of the figure could also help to make the test more visible.

Comment: Hi,I ment to figure - the picture it self..

Comment: @samcarter: But the paper size may be too small in order to increase the figure as well?

Comment: I think it does not important ( the size of it)

Comment: For example whn I am adding picture from MATLAB/Simulink

Comment: @ChristianHupfer There is always the possibility to print it as a poster :)

Comment: a png image is just a picture like a photograph, you can not sensibly change it from tex, you need to adjust the plotting in matlab.

Comment: @samcarter: You're the one that kills trees because wasting too much paper ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Maybe I should load the `savetrees` package? But I was under the impression you had enough trees around your home.

Comment: @samcarter: Oh my .... :D :D

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to "bolden" figures under 2 conditions:

1. You are using the Postscript route (`latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf`)
2. Your figures are line art (vector graphics)

For other workflows (pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX), PDF vector image files can be treated one by one, but must be converted to Postscript first. See below.

---

Here, we enhance line widths of the second figure by factor 3:

```
\pdfoutput=0 %force dvi output

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image}

\special{ps: userdict /setlinewidth {3 mul systemdict /setlinewidth get exec} put}
  \includegraphics{example-image}
\special{ps: userdict /setlinewidth undef} %undo

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

For single *vector* graphics files, the following template can be used. PDF files must be converted to Postscript first. The result can be converted back to PDF for inclusion in the main document, if this one is to be processed with pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Template to be processed with the `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` sequence of commands, using [**tiger.eps**](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/images/tiger.eps) as an example file:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%% adjust this %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\graphicsFile{tiger.eps}
\def\enhanceFactor{3}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pdfoutput=0 %force dvi output

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}%
\begin{preview}%
\special{ps: userdict /setlinewidth {\enhanceFactor\space mul systemdict /setlinewidth get exec} put}%
\includegraphics{\graphicsFile}%
\end{preview}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi,I am afriad that I did not got you...

Comment: What is Postscript route ? and figures are line art ? I use figures in file.png..

Comment: External graphics to be included are in Postscript (`*.ps`, `*.eps`) format  and you process your document with `latex`, followed by `dvips`, followed by `ps2pdf`.

Comment: Well, actually all my figures in format of file.png. and documentclass[a4paper]{report} - regarding to my thesis writing...

Comment: Matlab, for sure, can export to vector graphics.

Comment: @Tommt_tsa Using vector graphics will almost always give you a higher quality result -- especially if your images contain text.

Comment: amcarter: how to tell Simulink to use vector graphics ?

Comment: Hi,Is there any short or simple way to do it ?

Comment: To convince Simulink to produce vector output? I have no idea, because I have no access to Matlab/Simulink, but maybe its Handbook tells something. I would search for "export formats" or so.

Comment: @Tommt_tsa I searched a bit and found this user provided package: http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig . Indeed, Matlab doesn't seem to be able to write to EPS/PDF on its own. What a shame.