# How to write graphics using subfig package or other?

Tags: graphics, diagrams, subfig

[image: Can]

Can somebody help me with these two linear graphics? At least some hints, how to start. I would be very greatful.

Comment: For our clarification: Do you want to include multiple pictures into your document or do you want to create these figures inside your LaTeX document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Have a look at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf , wher you'll find the "Minimal introduction". Skimming through it will give an idea of the various concepts used. Next use the "PGF Manual" to review for more details. // For edamples and code you may also want to visit https://texample.net/tikz/examples/all/ .

Comment: @Hoerbii3 I want to create these figures inside my LaTeX document

Comment: Alright, then I think you can either use `PSTricks` or `tikz` (discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60778/fundamental-differences-pstricks-tikz-pgf-and-others) . Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possibility for the first graph, with `pstricks`:

```
    \documentclass[pstricks, border=6pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pstricks-add}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(6,6)
    \psset{linejoin=1, arrowinset=0.1}
    \psaxes[ticks=none, labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(6,6)[$ \Phi_1(t) $, -135][$ \Phi_2(t) $, -135]
    \pnodes(0,0){O}(4,0){A}(0,4){B}
    \ncline[linestyle=dashed]{B}{A} \naput[nrot=:U]{$\sqrt{2E_b}$}
    \psline[linewidth=1.2pt, linecolor=blue]{->}(O)(A)
    \psline[linewidth=1.2pt, linecolor=red]{->}(O)(B)
    \psbrace[nodesepA=-1em, nodesepB=1.25em](0,-0.2 )(4,-0.2){$\sqrt{E_b}$}
    \psbrace[nodesepA=-2em, nodesepB=0.5em](-0.2,4)(-0.2,0 ){$\sqrt{E_b}$}
    \end{pspicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for the code, it made it a lot easier for me to figure out how to do it on my own. I only had one question, how to implement this in already made  \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} , which library i need to include

Comment: @iiBum11: You can use the code as is in the artcle class. There is single problem; pdflatex doesn't have necessary tools to make the computations required  by postscript, so you to use either the standard way `latex –> dvi –>ps –>pdf`, or compile with `xelatex --shell-escape`.