# Is the package pst-poker compilable using pdfLaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, overleaf

Using overleaf, I've written a paper which uses the package pst-poker. XeLaTeX compiles it without errors, however pdfLatex compilation is problematic.

How can I use the package with pdfLatex?

Comment: No. `pst-poker` uses PSTricks which requires compilation with either `latex + dvips` or with `xelatex`.

Comment: make it an answer and I will acept it

Comment: does Overleaf support the `shell-escape` option? If yes then you can run it with `pdflatex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pst-poker` package (and all packages with the `pst-` prefix) uses PSTricks and therefore must be compiled with `latex + dvips` or `xelatex`. They will not work with `pdflatex` or `lualatex`.

For more details on why this is the case see:

- [Why doesn't pdfTeX support PStricks directly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24553/2693)

Comment: what is the best practice when tying to upload a paper that use pst-poker to arXiv?  arXiv accept only La)TeX, AMS(La)TeX, PDFLaTeX

Comment: @Cohensius Checking the  arXiv website,  it makes a distinction between LaTeX and pdfLaTeX, and you should be able to use LaTeX to compile with PSTricks.